# AVFoundation Record and Play from Bluetooth Headset

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation

I'd like to use `AVFoundation` to record the audio coming from a microphone in my bluetooth headset (AirPods) while volume still comes out of the speakers from the system/other apps. When I try to record with my AirPods selected as the microphone input source, the audio that comes through while recording is muddy and the resulting video can be corrupted.

On iOS it seems the proper method is to set the mode and category of `AVAudioSession`'s `sharedInstance`. How do I do something similar on Mac?

Comment: Have you tried creating an Aggregate Device consisting of AirPods in and Speakers out in the Audio MIDI Setup app and then selecting that as your in/out device? That should be enough for a one off, otherwise you can do the whole thing programmatically.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I'd love to do the whole thing programmatically. I wish this was a one-off, but I need to cover this case for our users since a significant portion of them use bluetooth headsets of some kind.

Comment: Interesting - well, if the manual approach works you can automate it - I've done it to make multiple output devices. Haven't tried input + output, but it should work.